# How to make PHP MYSQL Insert query only with values which are existed for certain columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 17 columns in my DB [image: db structure]

I'm inserting values from different sources. Somewhere I haven't, for example, company/company_info values (I'm setting in PHP FALSE values for relevant variables).

So, I need some kind of PHP INSERT query to insert only not empty variables and columns of certain list.

For example, I could do:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `$tname` (`phone`,`location`, `pagelang`, `company`, `company_url`, `phone_no_cc`, `phone_type`, `operator`, `pageviews`, `rating`, `comments_number`, `activity_by_days`, `activity_by_hours`) VALUES (
    '$main_number', '$number_advanced_info[location]', '$pagelang', '$company[name]', '$company[site]', '$number_advanced_info[number_no_countrycode]', '$number_advanced_info[phone_type]', '$number_advanced_info[operator]', '$searches_comments[searches]', '$rating', '$searches_comments[comments]', '$history_search', '$daily_history'                                                                                                                                                                                          
);";
```

With insert of 14 columns and their values.

But sometimes I need to insert less columns/values and let MYSQL set default values for not listed columns. For Example, I want to insert only 5 columns.

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `$tname` (`phone`,`location`, `pageviews`, `rating`) VALUES (
    '$main_number', '$number_advanced_info[location]', '$searches_comments[searches]', '$rating'                                                                                                                                                                                       
);";
```

**Is there some CLASS or any solution like binding values which will automatically build query depending which values are not NULL?**

I need some kind of code:

```
if (!$phone) {
$columns .= "`column_name`," ;
$values .= "value";
}
```

Comment: Yep, you need to write a query builder, like in the last piece of code you've shown. And note that your queries are vulnerable to SQL injections, use prepared statements

Comment: You can keep your 17-fields query as is and bind `DEFAULT` as value instead of a variable. MySQL will set the default value when inserting (it works too with auto_increment fields)